# Unfuddle svn access behind a proxy

Tags: svn, repository, unfuddle

I am using unfuddle to host some private projects, unfuddle is an excellent solution to being able to update and modify my sources through SVN anytime and when I feel like to even when I’m not home.

The problem is at work we are behind a mandatory proxy which I cannot disable, keeping me from accessing my unfuddle repository through SVN.

Is there any solution to this, or is there some free alternative to unfuddle which has not the proxy limitation ? I don’t care much about project management and bug  tracking like unfuddle provides, I just want to be able to have access to my source code through SVN anywhere I want to.

Comment: You tried getting a whitelist yet for unfuddle from the network engineer/sysadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many subversion hosters allow connecting to them via HTTPS. In that case the proxy server doesn't see the special subversion commands and usually passes them through transparently as when you would use https for a webserver only.

(I have no experience with unfuddle, but it worked in a few other cases)

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried to connect via HTTPS and even this is blocked by the proxy server.